# Can the 'auto' algorithm of the Symfony Security encoder change encoding method?

Tags: encoding, symfony-security, symfony-4.3

In Symfony 4.3, it is [recommended](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#c-encoding-passwords) to use the `auto` option for encoding algorithm:

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
# ...

encoders:
    # use your user class name here
    App\Entity\User:
        # Use native password encoder
        # This value auto-selects the best possible hashing algorithm.
        algorithm: auto
```

My question is in regards to the comment in the code above: can the algorithm change if the "best possible" algorithm changes? If so, how will this affect the currently existing stored passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

According to this [comment](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/31758#issuecomment-497632492) about an issue on the Symfony Github repository:

**[Security] 4.3 Always "Bad credentials." with algorithm "auto"**

> sodium can't validate bcrypt passwords, that's the issue.
>   of course you can't move from sha512 to auto/native/sodium without a migration plan (one will be provide in 4.4)

I guess compatibility will be ensured by [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium).
So I suppose users whom password has been hashed with the previous "best possible" algorithm will be able to login, but their password will **NOT** be re-hashed with the new "best possible" algorithm.

As for passwords hashed with an algorithm not supported by libsodium (e.g. **bcrypt**), users will **NOT** be able to login if you don't tell Symfony which encoder to use for these users specifically.

See the `getEncoderName()` method at https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/named_encoders.html to learn how to juggle with multiple encoders and tell Symfony which one to use.